# Print JSON starting with array with SwiftyJSON

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I am trying to print JSON in Swift 2.0 using SwiftyJSON and Alamofire

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://announcement.vassy.net/api/AnnouncementAPI/Get/").responseJSON { (Response) -> Void in

        //check if result has value
        if let value = Response.result.value {

            let json = JSON(value)

            print(json)

        }

    }
```

And it works perfectly fine, but when trying to access a specific string, this happens:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://announcement.vassy.net/api/AnnouncementAPI/Get/").responseJSON { (Response) -> Void in

        //check if result has value
        if let value = Response.result.value {

            let json = JSON(value)

            print(json["Body"].stringValue)

        }

    }
```

And this is a small part of the JSON file I'm fetching from the server:

```
[
  {
    "InsertDate" : "2016-02-19T05:00:00",
    "Title" : "Musical Theatre Yearbook Photo",
    "Body" : "This is a yearbook photo reminder.",
    "Id" : 34641
  }
]
```

I've been working on this for a while and cannot figure anything out, my gut is telling me that the JSON is fine, it's just the way the code is trying to print it.

Comment: does everything work fine on Postman (or something equivalent)?

Comment: @omar    check following answer it will solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the outer object is an array you have to print the value for a key **of the first item**

```
print(json[0]["Body"].stringValue)
```

Or printing all "bodies" in the array

```
for anItem in json.array {
    print(anItem["Body"].stringValue)
}
```

Comment: Awesome, that works! But I just one more question, how would I print all the  "Body" strings together?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://announcement.vassy.net/api/AnnouncementAPI/Get/").responseJSON 
 { (Response) -> Void in

//check if result has value
if let value = Response.result.value {

    let json = JSON(value)

//Do the parsing
if !json.isEmpty
{
    if let arrData = json.array
    {
        for dict in arrData
        {

             dict["Id"].int
             dict["Title"].string
             dict["Body"].string
             dict["InsertDate"].string
            //store this data into object add the object into array 

        }
    }
}
}
}
```